# Substantiate why the rotation invariant measure on $\mathcal{S}^{1}$ has uniform distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, rotations

$\mathcal{S}^{1}:=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}: x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}$

Show that the rotation invariant measure on $\mathcal{S}^{1}$ has uniform distribution. Via Polar Coordinates $(\theta \mapsto (\cos{(\theta)},\sin{(\theta)}))$  I want to consider the generator $\mathcal{C}:=\{[0,\beta[: \beta \in ]0,2\pi[\}$ of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S}^{1})$

Then by definition of $P$ being a rotation-invariant measure, we have

$P( [0,\beta[)=P([a,a+\beta[)$ for any $a \in \mathbb R$. By this definition, it is clear the measure has to be uniformly distributed, I am just unsure on how to substantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\ P\ $ is normalised so that $\ P\left(\mathcal{S}^1\right)=1\ $. Then
\begin{align}
P\left(\mathcal{S}^1\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}P\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[\frac{2\pi k}{n}, \frac{2\pi (k+1)}{n}\right[\right.\right\}\right)\\
&=nP\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[0, \frac{2\pi}{n}\right[\right.\right\}\right)\ ,
\end{align}
by the invariance of $\ P\ $.  Therefore
$$
P\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[\alpha,\alpha + \frac{2\pi}{n}\right[\right.\right\}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\ .
$$
Now, for $\ m\le n\ $,
$$
\hspace{-8em}P\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[0, \frac{2\pi m}{n}\right[\right.\right\}\right)=\\
\hspace{4em}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}P\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert
 \,\theta\in\left[\frac{2\pi k}{n}, \frac{2\pi (k+1)}{n}\right[\right.\right\}\right)\\
= \frac{m}{n}\ ,
$$
again, by the invariance of $\ P\ $. Thus,
$$
P\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[\alpha,\alpha + 2\pi q\right[\right.\right\}\right)=q\ ,
$$
for all rational $\ q\in[0,1]\ $.

Now if $\ 0<\beta\le\alpha+2\pi\ $ then there is an increasing sequence of rational numbers $\ \left\{r_k\right\}_{k=1}^\infty\ $ with $\ r_1>\alpha\ $ and $\ \lim_\limits{k\rightarrow\infty}r_i=\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2\pi}\ $, so
\begin{align}
P\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[\alpha,\alpha + \beta \right[\right.\right\}\right)&= P\left(\bigcup_\limits{k=1}^\infty\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[\alpha,\alpha + 2\pi r_k\right[\right.\right\}\right)\\
&=\lim_\limits{k\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left\{\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\left\vert \,\theta\in\left[\alpha,\alpha + 2\pi r_k\right[\right.\right\}\right)\\
&=\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2\pi}\ ,
\end{align}
which establishes the uniformity of $\ P\ $.